# Apache HttpClient5 - How to set LocalAddress per-request?

Tags: apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm migrating Apache httpclient from 4.5 to 5.3 and my app currently chooses from a set of local IPs dynamically.

Example code:

```java
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
request.setRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
    .setLocalAddress(someLocalInetAddress)
    .build());
```

In httpclient 5.x the setLocalAddress() has been removed and **I need a new way to assign the local address.**

I know I can create ConnectionSocketFactory on the ConnectionManager level but this doesn't work for me because it would require explicit configuration for when to use each IP (as far as I understand).
I have some other logic which determines the IP and I simply need to set it for the request.

**UPDATE:**

A "hack" I've found is to create a custom HttpContext and pass it like this

```java
//create a new HttpRoute route and set its local address
final HttpContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setAttribute(HTTP_ROUTE, httpRoute);

client.execute(request, context, handler);
```

The issue with this is that it overrides the whole httpRoute, not just the localAddress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a local address per request. It makes no sense. The local address can only be defined at the HTTP route level.

Subclass `DefaultRoutePlanner` and override its `#determineLocalAddress` method in order to provide a custom strategy for a local address resolution on a per HTTP route basis.

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setRoutePlanner(new DefaultRoutePlanner(DefaultSchemePortResolver.INSTANCE) {

            @Override
            protected InetAddress determineLocalAddress(final HttpHost firstHop, final HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
                return (InetAddress) context.getAttribute("local-address");
            }

        })
        .build()) {

    final ClassicHttpRequest request = ClassicRequestBuilder.get()
            .setHttpHost(new HttpHost("https", "httpbin.org"))
            .setPath("/headers")
            .build();
    final HttpClientContext clientContext = HttpClientContext.create();
    clientContext.setAttribute("local-address", InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1}));
    System.out.println("Executing request " + request);
    httpclient.execute(request, clientContext, response -> {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(request + "->" + new StatusLine(response));
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        return null;
    });
}
```

Comment: **I have updated the main post with a partial solution.** The problem with route planner is that it requires a thread-safe implementation but the existing logic for choosing an ip is very complex and not thread-safe. Should I create an HttpClient for every IP and pass the clients around as method params?

Comment: No, one should not create more than one HttpClient instance per distinct HTTP service. Using HttpContext to pass context specific parameters to a strategy is actually the correct way to go about it

Comment: Thanks for editing the main post, now it makes sense! I missed that you can add custom attributes and use them to resolve the local address.